# changing and setting one level of a multiindex dataframe with a function

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Assuming a multiindex dataframe as follows

**THE (DUMMY) DATA**

```
import pandas as pd

df={('AB30566', 'ACTIVE1', 'A1'): {('2021-01-01', 'PHOTO'): 2,
 ('2021-01-01', 'QUE'): 8,
 ('2021-01-01', 'TXR'): 4,
 ('2022-02-01', 'PHOTO'): 4,
 ('2022-02-01', 'QUE'): 0,
 ('2022-02-01', 'TXR'): 1,
 ('2022-03-01', 'PHOTO'): 9,
 ('2022-03-01', 'QUE'): 7,
 ('2022-03-01', 'TXR'): 7},
 ('CD55DF55', 'ACTIVE2', 'A2'): {('2021-01-01', 'PHOTO'): 1,
 ('2021-01-01', 'QUE'): 7,
 ('2021-01-01', 'TXR'): 0,
 ('2022-02-01', 'PHOTO'): 8,
 ('2022-02-01', 'QUE'): 8,
 ('2022-02-01', 'TXR'): 3,
 ('2022-03-01', 'PHOTO'): 6,
 ('2022-03-01', 'QUE'): 0,
 ('2022-03-01', 'TXR'): 7},
('ZT52556', 'UNACTIVE1', 'A3'): {('2021-01-01', 'PHOTO'): 8,
  ('2021-01-01', 'QUE'): 9,
  ('2021-01-01', 'TXR'): 3,
  ('2022-02-01', 'PHOTO'): 5,
  ('2022-02-01', 'QUE'): 3,
  ('2022-02-01', 'TXR'): 0,
  ('2022-03-01', 'PHOTO'): 7,
  ('2022-03-01', 'QUE'): 0,
  ('2022-03-01', 'TXR'): 9},
 ('MIKE90', 'PENSIONER1', 'A4'): {('2021-01-01', 'PHOTO'): 3,
  ('2021-01-01', 'QUE'): 9,
  ('2021-01-01', 'TXR'): 8,
  ('2022-02-01', 'PHOTO'): 3,
  ('2022-02-01', 'QUE'): 2,
  ('2022-02-01', 'TXR'): 1,
  ('2022-03-01', 'PHOTO'): 9,
  ('2022-03-01', 'QUE'): 0,
  ('2022-03-01', 'TXR'): 4},
 ('ZZ00001', 'ACTIVE3', 'A5'): {('2021-01-01', 'PHOTO'): 0,
  ('2021-01-01', 'QUE'): 2,
  ('2021-01-01', 'TXR'): 1,
  ('2022-02-01', 'PHOTO'): 2,
  ('2022-02-01', 'QUE'): 0,
  ('2022-02-01', 'TXR'): 8,
  ('2022-03-01', 'PHOTO'): 5,
  ('2022-03-01', 'QUE'): 6,
  ('2022-03-01', 'TXR'): 0}}
```

(The real case is much bigger of course)

I need to change the values of the names in the level 0 called userid based on a function.

I do it in the following way and this strange result happens:

**THE CODE & WRONG SOLUTION**

```
d=pd.DataFrame(f)
d.columns.names =["USERID", "STATUS","LEVEL"]
def simple_mask_user_id(userids):
    exam_dict = {userid:("EX"+str(i).zfill(5) if re.match(r"[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",userid) else userid) for i,userid in enumerate(userids) }
    return exam_dict
current_userids = d.columns.get_level_values('USERID').tolist()
dict_mask = simple_mask_user_id(current_userids)
display(d)
new_names = d.columns.get_level_values("USERID").map(dict_mask).tolist()
print(new_names)
d.columns.set_levels(new_names, level=0, inplace=True)
display(d)
```

The level USERID of the dataframe should be chaged accoring to the dict:

```
{'AB30566': 'EX00000', 'CD55DF55': 'CD55DF55', 'ZT52556': 'EX00002', 'MIKE90': 'MIKE90', 'ZZ00001': 'EX00004'}
```

**THE FAULTY RESULT**

I display the df to compared the result before and after.
The index got mixed.

MIKE90 and EX00002 gets changed by each other.

In other words, MIKE90 is not on top of the corresponding PENSIONER1, A4, which is the other levels corresponding to it (MIKE90 does not get changed)
You can also see that the order of the list new names has the correct order.

**THE QUESTIONS**

Why?
How do you change one level of the multindex without altering the data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `MultiIndex.map` and a given mapping dictionary (`d`) to substitue level=0 values

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda c: (d[c[0]], *c[1:]))
```

Result

```
                 EX00000 CD55DF55   EX00002     MIKE90 EX00004
                 ACTIVE1  ACTIVE2 UNACTIVE1 PENSIONER1 ACTIVE3
                      A1       A2        A3         A4      A5
2021-01-01 PHOTO       2        1         8          3       0
           QUE         8        7         9          9       2
           TXR         4        0         3          8       1
2022-02-01 PHOTO       4        8         5          3       2
           QUE         0        8         3          2       0
           TXR         1        3         0          1       8
2022-03-01 PHOTO       9        6         7          9       5
           QUE         7        0         0          0       6
           TXR         7        7         9          4       0
```

Comment: Can you comment what is c in your comment? is a multindex level? is the whole multindex?

Comment: @JFerro c is basically a single item from multiindex i.e. a tuple `('AB30566', 'ACTIVE1', 'A1')`..`map` will iterate over all such items and apply a lambda function

Comment: You can also use a comprehension if its easier for you to understand: `df.columns = [(d[x], *y) for x, *y in df.columns]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename` by first level of `MultiIndex` with `dict.get` - if no match return original value (second parameter `x`):

```
#same key values should be omitted
d = {'AB30566': 'EX00000', 'ZT52556': 'EX00002', 'ZZ00001': 'EX00004'}
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: d.get(x,x), level=0)
print (df)
                 EX00000 CD55DF55   EX00002     MIKE90 EX00004
                 ACTIVE1  ACTIVE2 UNACTIVE1 PENSIONER1 ACTIVE3
                      A1       A2        A3         A4      A5
2021-01-01 PHOTO       2        1         8          3       0
           QUE         8        7         9          9       2
           TXR         4        0         3          8       1
2022-02-01 PHOTO       4        8         5          3       2
           QUE         0        8         3          2       0
           TXR         1        3         0          1       8
2022-03-01 PHOTO       9        6         7          9       5
           QUE         7        0         0          0       6
           TXR         7        7         9          4       0
```

If dictionary has keys by all columns:

```
d = {'AB30566': 'EX00000', 'CD55DF55': 'CD55DF55', 
     'ZT52556': 'EX00002', 'MIKE90': 'MIKE90', 'ZZ00001': 'EX00004'}
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: d[x], level=0)
print (df)
                 EX00000 CD55DF55   EX00002     MIKE90 EX00004
                 ACTIVE1  ACTIVE2 UNACTIVE1 PENSIONER1 ACTIVE3
                      A1       A2        A3         A4      A5
2021-01-01 PHOTO       2        1         8          3       0
           QUE         8        7         9          9       2
           TXR         4        0         3          8       1
2022-02-01 PHOTO       4        8         5          3       2
           QUE         0        8         3          2       0
           TXR         1        3         0          1       8
2022-03-01 PHOTO       9        6         7          9       5
           QUE         7        0         0          0       6
           TXR         7        7         9          4       0
```

Answer (score 0):

**CODE FOR TIMING**

```
df_anonym = df.copy(deep=True)

%%timeit
df_anonym.columns.map(lambda c: (dict_mask.get(c[0],"UNKONOWN"), *c[1:]))

df_anonym2 = df.copy(deep=True)

%%timeit
df_anonym2.columns = [(dict_mask.get(x,"UNKNOWN"), *y) for x, *y in df_anonym2.columns]

df_anonym3 = df.copy(deep=True)

%%timeit
df_anonym3.rename(columns=lambda x: dict_mask.get(x,"UNKNOWN"), level=0)
```

**RESULTS**
List comprehension: winner
Map: second
Rename: waaaaaay slowwer

[image]

Comment: Is possible test `df_anonym2.columns = df_anonym2.columns.set_levels([dict_mask.get(x,"UNKNOWN") for x in df_anonym2.columns.levels[0]], level=0)` ? If use `df_anonym2.columns = [(dict_mask.get(x,"UNKNOWN"), *y) for x, *y in df_anonym2.columns]` it return `MultiIndex` ? Because for me working `df_anonym2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(dict_mask.get(x,"UNKNOWN"), *y) for x, *y in df_anonym2.columns])`